# How does one increase elasticsearch document limit/indice count?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

My elasticsearch server currently houses 5B Documents. However, it stopped indexing from out DB and our DB holds 7B Records. I currently only have 5 shards:

> "number_of_shards": "5",

How can i increase this? Will increasing this alow for more data retention? The server is 4TB SSD and currently only using 800GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shard has a max document count limit to 2.1B/shard. So, your current shard config should allow for storing around ~ 10B docs per index. However, it is recommended to keep each shard size between 20 - 50 GB for optimum performance and anything larger than 50 GB can be a problem during reallocating/ recovering.

You may increase the number of primary shards as long as you have hardware that can accommodate it. Please note every shard by itself consumes cluster resources (memory/cpu) and has a cost towards cluster overhead. We have had some significant performance issues when our clusters were over sharded.

*Each Elasticsearch shard is a Lucene index. There is a maximum number of documents you can have in a single Lucene index. As of LUCENE-5843, the limit is 2,147,483,519 (= Integer.MAX_VALUE - 128) documents*

Comment: I read that earlier. Could you point me towards the correct direction for re-sharding? i don't want to lose any data. Is simply setting a new shard limit sufficient to achieve this?

Comment: Consider if you really need re-sharding ? What is the problem with current shard config ?

Comment: sorry for the huge delay in response. Wouldn't re-sharding increase performance and allow for more records?

Comment: "Please note every shard by itself consumes cluster resources (memory/cpu) and has a cost towards cluster overhead. We have had some significant performance issues when our clusters were over sharded". If you are seeing shard sizes over > 50 GB then consider increasing the number of shards otherwise you'd end up with oversharding.

Comment: What would a reccomended shard count be for 4TB SSD storage, 64GB Ram, 4.22GH Quadcore CPU?